# Method average in class Student cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm getting the error above in my program. It highlights this line of code in the Course class:

> return (s1.average() + s1.average() + s1.average() + s1.average() + s1.average()) / 5.0;

This is the Course class. The reason why brackets were commented out was because my instructor told me to do this.

```
public class Course extends Student
{
private String course;
private Student s1, s2, s3, s4, s5;
private int studentcount = 1;

public Course (String name)
{
   super(); //
   course = name;

}

public Student addStudent(String first, String last, Address home, Address school)
{

//if (studentcount == 1){
  s1 = new Student(first,last,home,school);
  studentcount++;          
  return s1;
//}    

 //if (studentcount == 2) {
  s2 = new Student(first,last,home,school);
      studentcount++;
  return s2;

//}
//else if (studentcount == 3){
  s3 = new Student(first,last,home,school);
  studentcount++;
      return s3;

//}
// else if (studentcount == 4){
  s4 = new Student(first,last,home,school);
      studentcount++;
  return s4;

//}
//else if (studentcount == 5) {
  s5 = new Student(first,last,home,school);
      studentcount++;
   return s5;

 //}
//else {
System.out.println("No More students allowed in the class");
return null;
//}
}

public double average()
{

}

public String roll()
{
String results = "";

if (studentcount == 1){
  results += s1.toString () +"n";
  return results;
}    

 if (studentcount == 2) {
  results += s1.toString () +"n";
  results += s2.toString () +"n";
  return results;

}
else if (studentcount == 3){
  results += s1.toString () +"n";
  results += s2.toString () +"n";
  results += s3.toString () +"n";
  return results;

}
else if (studentcount == 4){
  results += s1.toString () +"n";
  results += s2.toString () +"n";
  results += s3.toString () +"n";
  results += s4.toString () +"n";
  return results;

}
else if (studentcount == 5) {
  results += s1.toString () +"n";
  results += s2.toString () +"n";
  results += s3.toString () +"n";
  results += s4.toString () +"n";
  results += s5.toString () +"n";

  return results;
    } 
    else{
  return null;
}   

}
}
```

This is the Student class:

```
public class Student 
{
Address home = new Address("1027 Charleston St","Lincoln", "Ne", 68508);
Address school = new Address("1534 E St", "Lincoln", "Ne", 68508);
Student mike = new Student("Mike", "Vinci", home, school);
Student john = new Student("John", "Doe", home, school, 90, 80, 199);

//Below are the ints used
int test1 = 0;
int test2 = 0;
int test3 = 0;
int avg2;
int error = 0;

public Student(){
     //empty
}

public void setTestScore(int testNum, int score)
{
    if (testNum == 1)
        test1 = score;
    else if (testNum == 2)
        test2 = score;
    else if (testNum == 3)
        test3 = score;
}

public int getTestScore(int testNum)
{
    if (testNum == 1)
        return test1;
    else if (testNum == 2)
        return test2;
    else if (testNum == 3)
        return test3;
    else
         return error;
}

public double average(int test1, int test2, int test3)
{
    int avg2 = ((test1 + test2 + test3)/3); //finds the average of the tests
    return avg2;
}

private String firstName, lastName; //private ints for coding
private Address homeAddress, schoolAddress;

public Student (String first, String last, Address home, Address school) 
{
    firstName = first;
    lastName = last;
    homeAddress = home;
    schoolAddress = school;
}

public Student (String first, String last, Address home, Address school, int test11, int test22, int test33) 
{
    firstName = first;
    lastName = last;
    homeAddress = home;
    schoolAddress = school;
    test11 = test1;
    test22 = test2;
    test33 = test3;
}

public String toString() 
{
    String result;
    result = firstName + " " + lastName + "\n";
    result += "Home Address:\n" + homeAddress + "\n";
    result += "School Address:\n" + schoolAddress + "\n";
    result += "Average=" + avg2 + " with Tests: " + test1 + ", " + test2 + ", " + test3;
    return result; //returns the result
}

class Address
{
private String streetAddress, city, state;
private long zipCode;

public Address(String street, String town, String st, long zip)
{
    streetAddress = street;
    city = town;
    state = st;
    zipCode = zip;
}

public String toString()
{
    String result;
    result = streetAddress + "\n";
    result += city + "," + state + " " + zipCode;
    return result; //returns the result
}
} 
}
```

So the question is **how would I fix this error?**

Comment: so what is the question: exactly? what do you expect us to answer to?

Comment: How do I fix this error? sorry i will add this to the post

Comment: be precise in asking a "good" question - other will tend to give you better answers if they understand exactly what you are looking for ;)

Comment: The method `average` in class `Student` expects 3 arguments, but you are calling it without any arguments - that's why you get this error. You should probably remove the parameters for that method in class `Student`, you want it to work on the member variables instead of on values that you pass.

Comment: I can only assume you mean to use `s1.average() + s2.average + [...] + s5.average()`.

Comment: are you sure you want to return `int` for your average method. you should consider returning double, or float so you can have decimal values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your error is to remove the parameters for your `average()` method, under the assumption that your `test1`, `test2`, and `test3` values will be set prior to calling that method. Perhaps you should have some checks for null values therein?

```
public int average()
{
    int avg2 = ((test1 + test2 + test3)/3); //finds the average of the tests
    return avg2;
}
```

Though it is likely more applicable to return a `double` in the above method, as [@MarquisBlount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33043666/method-average-in-class-student-cannot-be-applied-to-given-types/33043808#comment53908255_33043666) mentioned:

Since you declare `avg2` as an instance variable, you can update it with `average()` for use later. With your current code, `avg2` isn't ever set for your printout, because you're creating a new variable relevant only to the method scope: `int avg2 = (( ...` and its value is discarded once returned.

I'm suggesting the below changes:

- Change `avg2` from an `int` to a `double`
- Set that class variable from within `average()`

Visualized:

```
double avg2;

...

public int average()
{
    avg2 = ((test1 + test2 + test3)/3); //finds the average of the tests
    return avg2;
}
```

Though you can just as well instantiate `avg2` to zero in the same line you declare it and simply "update" it using `average()` :

```
double avg2 = 0;
```

---

As a result, within your Course class's `double average()` method you can call:

```
public double average()
{
    return (s1.average() + s2.average() + s3.average() + s4.average() + s5.average()) / 5.0;
}
```

again, inferring all values are populated prior to each call. Though it looks like you have your application workflow already built around those assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling :

```
return (s1.average() + s1.average() + s1.average() + s1.average() + s1.average()) / 5.0
```

call :

```
return (s1.average(s1.test1,s1.test2,s1.test3) + s2.average(s2.test1,s2.test2,s2.test3) + s3.average(s3.test1,s3.test2,s3.test3) + s4.average(s4.test1,s4.test2,s4.test3) + s5.average(s5.test1,s5.test2,s5.test3)) / 5.0
```

Comment: I don't think this is the best way. Each class already has access to those instant variables, why retrieve them from each class only to send them back as method arguments?

Comment: I didn't see your update @Trobbins , I will have to come back online later